# I Can't raise the brightness to the maximum.

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a macbook pro late 2008. When Im raising the brighntess level, when it reaches the 50% it starts to decrease the brightness till it goes almost dark on 100%. Someone know how to do fix this?

thanks

Comment: Weird. I recommend that you try to reset the SMC. There is a guide here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

Answer (score 1):

take a look at your settings! so you dont have automatic brightness on,[image: take a look] that COULD prevent it! "could.." second thing i would do is an [SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) reset! if this doesn't work get back and we can to a little more trouble shooting!